# How to delete a row/column from a sparse table in constant time?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have a **very sparsely** filled table with **huge dimensions**.

i.e, the indices of my table can be very large but the number of elements in the table is very less.

I have been thinking of a data structure for this.

I ruled out an `rows x cols` table because it takes too much memory and too much time for finding all the elements in a row/column.

Instead I thought of using two maps: `rows` and `cols`.

Let's see `rows`. The keys are row indices and the value for a key `k` is a list of column numbers of all elements that are in row `k`.

example (1 means an element is present there):

```
0 1 0
1 0 1
```

would be this `rows` map:

```
0: [1]
1: [0, 2]
```

I would keep a similar `cols` map where keys are column numbers and the value for a key `k` is a list of row numbers of all elements that are in column `k`.

When I want to delete a row `k` in my table, I would do:
`del rows[k]`

But this will not delete the vertices from `cols` map.
I would have to iterate through all the columns where some element got deleted and delete each element from the `cols` map.

Is there an `O(1)` method of doing this?

Comment: Isn't the information on rows enough, why do you need a map for columns?

Comment: @Joni, for quick access. I'll need to quickly know how many elements are there in a particular column.

Comment: Instead of optimizing row deletion I think you need to take a look at all the read and write operations you will perform on the table through its whole life cycle and optimize for that total.

Comment: If you need the number of elements for a given column instead of having a second (redundant) map for columns, maybe you could use a dictionary where you keep track of the nonzero counts of elements, using the col number as the key.

Comment: By "delete" you mean, set all entries to zero, right? Or do you remove the row completely and have the rows below shift up?

Comment: And you would like to delete both rows and columns?

Comment: @ErikP., by delete just set the value of the key to `NULL`. Since deletion of a key in the middle of a hash array isn't `O(1)`.

Comment: @ErikP., Yes, I'd want to delete both rows and columns. I just used rows to explain. There is no difference between rows and columns as such.

Comment: @neural5torm, But I need to delete columns too. When I delete a column I'd have to look at which rows had elements in the column and delete them also.

Comment: @NovaDenizen, the table is filled just once in the beginning. It would take `O(n)` time where n in the number of elements. I repeatedly need to know how many elements are there in a given row/column and be able to delete a row/column.

Comment: Since it's so sparse, why is this a problem? Your delete row operation takes `O(<# entries in row>*<# entries in columns of elements in row>)`. In the average case this could well be less than a couple of operations.

Comment: @clwhisk, good point. It shouldn't be very costly. But I'm just curious to know what data structure could help this bit of improvement.

Comment: @Dukeling oh I see... Wouldn't the [time-complexity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/time-complexity) tag be more appropriate then? thanks

Comment: You can mark a column inactive in constant time by setting a boolean flag. The only time you actually need to traverse the list is if adding the column again.

Answer (score 2):

A very unorthodox way of approaching this would be to implement the matrix as a *k*d-tree, with *k*=2. You would delete a row or column by visiting all cells that intersect that row or column; if the matrix is square and it has `n` nonzero entries, the average number of cells you'll need to examine is `sqrt(n)`, I believe. (I have written a proof to that effect in some answer here on Stackoverflow - I can look it up if you need it.)

In a very similar vein, you could use a quadtree; the way I understand these terms, the difference is that the cell boundaries are pre-defined to always cut the x- and y-range into halves (for four identical subcells in every non-leaf) in a quadtree, whereas the nodes determine the boundaries in a *k*d-tree (for two non-identical subcells in every non-leaf).

I think for both versions, the performance of this solution depends on the sparsity in a complicated way. First of all, if the data is truly very sparse, as in, the average number of nonzero entries per row/column is much less than one, then this solution will be much more memory-efficient than the one you propose, but probably less time-efficient. If the number of nonzero entries is some constant fraction `c` of the total number of entries, and your matrix is `m * k`, this solution might be more efficient: for your solution, to delete one column you would need to change, on average, `c*m` row lists. For each such row list, you would need to find the spot where your column is and move all entries coming after it, one forward. That is on average `c*k/2 = O(k)` entries in each row, for a total of `c^2*m*k/2 = O(m*k)` operations. We would have `n = c*m*k`, so the average total number of operations would be `c*n/2 = O(n)` whereas it would be `O(sqrt(n))` for the solutions proposed here. Similarly, if you assume the matrix is roughly square, say `m*m`, and each row/column has `f(m)` nonzero entries on average (so that `n = f(m)*m`), then the number of operations is `O(f(m)^2)` for your solution and `O(sqrt(m*f(m)))` for this one; that means, this solution is better if `f(m) = ω(m^(1/3))`. (Note that was a [lower case omega](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_oh_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations); it basically means, `f(m)` grows asymptotically faster than `m^(1/3)`, for example like `sqrt(m)` or `c*m`.)

(I was assuming that each entry of the `rows` map is an array in your solution; a linked list would give the same complexity because it takes linear time to find the right column in the list. You could do a little better by having each row and column represented, not by an array, but by a self-balancing tree -- then you could get away with `O(log(k))` operations for each row and `O(m * log(k)) = O(sqrt(n)*log(n))` in total, assuming the matrix is not too far from being square. Still not better than this tree business, but if you really need the best performance it might be worth implementing to see how it works in practice.)

If the density of your matrix is indeed a constant `c`, then a dense matrix representation would also do `O(sqrt(n))` operations, so the asymptotic behaviour should be the same. The constant factors would depend on `c`, so once again, you'd need to implement both in order to be certain which is faster.

For the quadtree solution to have good performance, you would additionally need the nonzero values to not be concentrated in a small area; the distribution doesn't need to be particularly even, just not extremely concentrated.

If you also expect to do frequent addition and removal of arbitrary entries, the *k*d-tree is very tricky to do well - I don't think there are easy schemes to make the tree balance itself, like red-black or AVL or similar 1-d trees. A quadtree could still work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But why do you say a kd-tree does better when the average number of nonzero entries per row/column is much less than one? The way I see, in my solution you get the elements of a row/column right away. Then it is a matter of iterating through them to update the other map before deleting the row/column. In kd-tree we would have to consider `sqrt(n)` elements to just find which of them are in a given row/column. Can you please explain?

Comment: @learner I expanded substantially. I was wrong about my intuition on what property of the sparsity you need if you want to be faster than your solution. I just realized I want to add another remark comparing it to a dense representation.

Answer (score 1):

Lets see if I understand what you have:

- For each row you maintain a list of columns that are occupied.
- For each column you maintain a list of rows that are occupied.
- Each of these structures on their own is sufficient to describe the matrx.

When a row is deleted you just set its associated column list to empty. But before doing
that, why not use this list to process the row lists for each column in that list?

A simple example. Suppose you have the following matrix:

```
   1 0 0 0 1 1
   0 1 0 0 0 0
   0 1 1 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 0 1
```

The column list for each row would be:

```
   0 [0, 4, 5]
   1 [1]
   2 [1, 2]
   3 [5]
```

The row list for each column would be:

```
   0 [1]
   1 [1, 2]
   2 [2]
   3 []
   4 [0]
   5 [0, 3]
```

If row 2 was to be deleted then you would process the column list associated with that row, in this case: `2 [1, 2]`. These are the
columns where the row lists will contain a '2'. None of the other
row lists need to be looked at.

```
   Delete row 2: 
    -Column list for row 2: [1, 2]
    -Remove row '2' from the row list for columns 1 and 2
    -Set column list for row 2 to []
   done.
```

The updated column list is:

```
   0 [0, 4, 5]
   1 [1]
   2 []   <== updated
   3 [5]
```

The updated row list is:

```
   0 [1]
   1 [1]  <== updated
   2 []   <== updated
   3 []
   4 [0]
   5 [0, 3]
```

Both of these structures describe the following matrix:

```
   1 0 0 0 1 1
   0 1 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 0 1
```

This is not the O(1) algorithm you were looking for, but it should be reasonably efficient for a very sparce matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have been thinking and thinking and I think it is possible.

The solution is however not ideal, because it may be O(1) in the beginning, but O(n) dependency is still there, however for some type of data and usage, it should be near the constant time.  So it depends if it is useful to you (the number of changes is dramatically less compared to length of arrays and/or number of operations).

For every delete, you should add into the "list of changes" that change. For example, you delete the line no. 10, so you add into your list : "above no. 10, subtract 1".

When counting the right line, you have to subtract/add through the "list of changes".

Also you need one more array, which contains the last subtracted/added number used and the number of "list of changes", so you don't have to count the changes already counted for that line.

In worst case it is still "a*n", where a is some constant.

---

Example :

```
rows, cols = 1000;
delete(row,573);
//=> list_of_changes[0] = {573, 'deleted'}
access_row(581)
//=> help_array[581] = {-1, 1}
//=> help_array.structure = {"how much add/subtract on this line", "number of changes used"}
access_row(581)
//=> look at the help_array[581] seeing having used 1 change,
//   the size of list_of_change is 1, so you don't have to count
//   anything, using the -1 value. - constant time
```

---

Of course, if I delete row[0] and then I access all the 0..998 values, it will be the O(n) cause it has to count n times the help_array.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand this answer properly. So how does deletion of a row get update the `cols` map? Or are you suggesting another data structure altogether?

Comment: They are updating with help of "help_array", but only if the column is accessed, it is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Since your main use of the `cols` map is to count the columns as quickly as possible, not get data from it, I would create a `table` with nested maps, and a `colCount` map instead of `rows` and `cols`.

This solution is closer to O(n) than O(1), but you won't have the wasted cycles present in a `row x cols` structure.

So, for your example, `table` would look like this:

```
{0: {1:"Value"},
{1: {0:"Value", 2:"Value"}}
```

And `colCount` would look like this:

```
#Each column in the example only had one value

{0:1,
 1:1,
 2:1}
```

Then, when you delete row `k`, you just decrement the counter for each of the columns found in the row. Here's some pseudo-code:

```
for key in table[k].keys()
    colCount[key] = colCount[key] - 1
delete table[k]
```

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, but I need to be able to delete columns as well. The purpose of `cols` is not just for counting the number of elements in a column.

Answer (score 0):

There's always Donald Knuth's [dancing links technique](http://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~jchu/publicportal/sudoku/sudoku.paper.html).  You use doubly linked lists along each row and column.  Deleting a row or column requires time linear in the number of elements in the row or column.